Kali Linux Hostname
I have tried to get rid of this space on my host name in my Kali box:
ehern㉿  kali-linux

I have tried to modify the /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts files with Vim and still the space before the host name remains.
Any way for me to get rid of it?

Is the space actually in the hostname, or just in the shell prompt string? Note that you'll probably need to start a new shell to have hostname changes become visible in the shell prompt.

What does printf '%s\n' "$PS1" output?

"I have tried to modify the /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts files" - was there actually a space in the hostname in either of these two files?

It is extremely unlikely that your hostname contains a space. You can check it with:
echo "-$(hostname)-"

which will probably return -kali-linux-, so without a space.
The space is probably in your definition of your prompt. You can override the prompt definition in your own .bashrc, if you don't like the system default:
PS1='spaceless_\u@\h:\w\$'


I believe Kali uses the zsh shell as the default shell, not bash. But then again, the user may be using fish for whatever we know.
